# how to conditionally adjust height of blob field in crystal reports?

Tags: image, crystal-reports, height

my report looks like this:

```
groupheader
  question       answer

  q1             a1
  q2             a2
  ...            ...
```

In most cases the answers are text. But one answer is an image. What i have done is to  insert the image and supress it conditionally (only show on the last row). This works fine. But the height of the supressed image is preserved, which causes the rows to be to high.

While you can conditionally set the width of an image you cannot do for the height apperently.

Does anybody have a solution?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot conditionally change size of an image.

A workaround I can think of, but I have not tried so I'm not sure it works, is to have a 1px x 1px image (or rather a 1px x 1px OLE object) in the report and then conditionally change the picture as described in "To make a static OLE object dynamic" in the Crystal reports help file.